# Auto "jumpmark" on a site without adding the #region to the link?

Tags: html, hyperlink, hashtag

If you like to jump on a website to a specific position you add a hashtag for the postion, for example:

```
www.mysite.com/category/file1#info
```

Would it be possible to set the jump for every site in the category folder to jump automatically to #info without setting in the the link?

Like, when I would share any of these links:

```
www.mysite.com/category/file1
www.mysite.com/category/file2
www.mysite.com/category/file3
```

it would then jump to **#info** automatically.

If this is possible what would be an approach/solution?

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that you'd prefer a client-side technology to do this, rather than server-side ([asp](/questions/tagged/asp), [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), [php](/questions/tagged/php), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)...), and that you're happy to use JavaScript, then the following solution will change the `href` attribute of *all* `a` elements with a `href` that includes the `category` folder:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    var cur = links[i],
        h = cur.href;
    if (h.indexOf('/category/') !== -1) {
        cur.href = h + '#info';
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ckqYp/1/).

Or, a little more  concisely, using a ternary operator to do exactly the same thing (albeit this time explicitly returning the `href` if it's not to be changed:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    var cur = links[i],
        h = cur.href;
    cur.href = h.indexOf('/category/') !== -1 ? h + '#info' : h;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ckqYp/2/).

Comment: Thank you for you quick and nice answer! This is a nice solution for adding the #info the existing links in the page and I can definitely use this also. But what I meant was adding the #info the a link, that is typed into the browser. Like, when I put www.mysite.com/category/ANYFILE into the browser #info will be automatically added like www.mysite.com/category/ANYFILE#info and the page jumps to the marker. The reason is that I don't want to share the links with #info on the end but just the link and then #info get's added. Is this possible?